# Couchbase Security

Tags: security, couchbase, encryption

Could anyone point me to documentation of encryption options available for couchbase? With SQL Server we have the option to encrypt data at table or db level. Is it possible to encrypt couchbase data in a similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Gazzang is what you want to look at in regards to data encryption for Couchbase:

> Gazzang for Couchbase offers a powerful, policy-driven solution that enables you to encrypt your data stored in Couchbase Server. With Gazzang, data files in Couchbase Server are encrypted on disk. This ensures that your data is not compromised if your database is stolen, copied, lost, or otherwise improperly accessed.

Source and more information on Gazzang:  http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/connectors/gazzang

Answer (score 1):

You could also use file system encryption - windows provides the option.